# Broken configuration distributed -- How do I fix

Tags: texmaker, build-system

Forgive me if this sounds dumb, this is my first use of TeX, and I'm working from my distro's broken package(s).  I am receiving output saying different things, depending on small run changes from cli and TeXmaker.  Among them are "logfile not found", "comment not found", "Processing error(s)", and when I run `fmtutil-sys --all` I get the following output: http://pastebin.com/YEcD7L7Z

Comment: If you are new to TeX, why are you messing about with `fmtutil-sys`?  Why are your distro's packages broken?  What happens if you try to do `latex small2e` from the command line?

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

I tried running it because it was on the archlinux forums that it fixes some problems.

As to the why, I don't know.  I also read on the forums that they are broken.  It is suggested that it is from some package changes, but that may be unrelated.

Comment: If Arch's repositories are broken (I hadn't heard that), then I would suggest purging the install and installing TeX Live from [TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).  That way you get an up-to-date system, and one that includes the very useful `tlmgr` as well.  (I long resisted, sticking with the Debian repositories, but there are true advantages to avoiding the repositories in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arch has noted that the packages are broken at this time.  The fix is listed on this page:

https://www.archlinux.org/news/texlive-2013-update-may-require-user-intervention/

Comment: Although not an Arch user, I highly recommend following the advice given in the last line of your link: "Removing TeXLive 2012 before installing TeXLive 2013 can also workaround the issue."